# UEFI install ubuntu on usb drive

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation, uefi

I have laptop MSI GP70 and I am able to boot installation from first USB stick and install it on second USB stick, then when I want to boot installed system from second USB drive I am unable to do so, even pressing F11 this drive is not listed in possible boot drives... on the other hand I am able to boot this USB on other laptop without UEFI and MSI stuff - any ideas how to boot this pendrive in MSI laptop?

additional: maybe if there were possibility to create EFI partition to boot system then it would solve problem?

---

**Solution** I had problem a problem getting into bios (DEL key but it's pure luck when to click to reach bios) it turned out that my 32GB SanDisk USB drive was HDD Drive and this option wasn't set in BIOS now it's ok - also I turned boot option from UEFI to LEGACY and it worked

Comment: Anyway, you might be interested in these articles to understand what's going on: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/ (I used them to implement UEFI in ALT Linux, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I had problem a problem getting into bios (DEL key but it's pure luck when to click it to reach bios) it turned out that my 32GB SanDisk USB drive was "USB HDD Drive" instead of "USB Key" and this option wasn't set in BIOS now it's ok - also I turned boot option from UEFI to LEGACY and it worked